# Blocking friends sql (super slow sql??)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, blocked

Hi im having trouble with this sql. Basically it displays statuses that my friends posted, and it filters out the friends that i blocked.

The sql is slooooowwwwwww though.. It takes 2 seconds to process it. What seems to be the problem. (ive listed the tables and some examples of how it looks below the sql) thanks in advance!
The sql....

```
SELECT from_user_id,content,wall.date, wall.wall_type, users.id, users.displayname 
            FROM wall

            INNER JOIN friendship ON ( wall.from_user_id =friendship.user_a OR wall.from_user_id = friendship.user_b ) 
            INNER JOIN users ON (wall.from_user_id = users.id)WHERE users.id not in (select blocked_id from blocklist where user_id = 1) and (wall.wall_type = 'home' OR wall.wall_type = 'profile' or wall.wall_type = 'topro') AND (
                  (friendship.user_a = 1 and friendship.user_b = wall.from_user_id)
                or  
                    (friendship.user_a = wall.from_user_id and friendship.user_b = 1)    or (wall.user_id_of_wall = 1 or type_id = 1 or from_user_id = 1))GROUP BY wall_id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10
```

(table name: blocklist)

```
    user_id | blocked_id
        1     74
        1     70
        1     94
        1     81
```

(table name:friendhip)

```
user_a   user_b status  date
1        93         1   1297323354
1        79         1   1297323409
1        81         1   1297323403
1        82         1   1297323398
1        85         1   1297323389
1        90         1   1297323367
1        89         1   1297323373
```

(table name:users)

```
       id   displayname
        1   Kenny  Jack
        8   Wale Robinson
        7   Victor WIlliams
        6   Micheal Harris
        9   Micheal Boston
        10  Yestor Smith
```

the wall table

```
wall_id wall_type   user_id_of_wall   type_id   from_user_id    content      viewed   date
   5    profile        8                    8          8         Just chilling! 0   1296858001
```

THANKS!!!

Comment: Could you please post the `EXPLAIN` output for your query? What are the indexes on the `friendship` table?

Comment: `UNION` s are probably better than `OR` s...

Comment: My guess is that the sub-select is the culprit. Would it be possible to find a query that takes the blocklist into account without the subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOT IN is used for fixed values, use NOT EXISTS instead :

```
SELECT from_user_id,content,wall.date, wall.wall_type, users.id, users.displayname 
            FROM wall

            INNER JOIN friendship ON ( wall.from_user_id =friendship.user_a OR wall.from_user_id = friendship.user_b ) 
            INNER JOIN users ON (wall.from_user_id = users.id)
WHERE not exists (select * from blocklist where users.id = blocked_id AND user_id = 1) and wall.wall_type IN ('home', 'profile', 'topro') AND (
                  (friendship.user_a = 1 and friendship.user_b = wall.from_user_id)
                or  
                    (friendship.user_a = wall.from_user_id and friendship.user_b = 1)    or (wall.user_id_of_wall = 1 or type_id = 1 or from_user_id = 1))
GROUP BY wall_id
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10
```

[EDIT] Use IN for fixed values (wall_type)...

Answer (score 0):

always use WITH (NOLOCK) on read-only queries!

also, please remove all your paranthesis on your JOIN clause, did you copy and paste this from MS Access?